# Casting multiple choice to array in Laravel/PHP returning Err:Array to string Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a small Pizza ordering app using Laravel, the objective of this question is to add toppings into an SQL column called toppings.

Everything works as intended apart from the toppings. If the user selects multiple toppings to be added the options will need to be combined into an array and then into a string value within the toppings sql column.
The resource I am following shows their mySQL table with:
[image: resource sql result]

Please notice the final column [toppings], an array of toppings selected.

I have tried to incorporate this on my own, I have also looked at other resources and followed them to the "T" but still the issue is there.

I must say everything is working correctly just not the toppings.

I have taken screenshots as I believe it would be easier to understand.

[image: html web form]

This is the webform layout, toppings[array] specified for each topping checkbox.
The migrations:

[image: CreatePizza_Migration]

As we can see json has been specified for toppings.

The PizzaController:

[image: PizzaController]

I am requesting the toppings that have been selected.

[image: Pizza Model]

According to the resources I am following image [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTE3M.png) seems to be the issue. When I go onto the route pizza/create - which works and enter a name and select a few toppings as shown here.

[image: Pizza webform]

Note: even if you select a single topping the next error presents itself.

[image: Array to String Conversion]

I am not sure how to fix this, if anybody has any ideas. I would greatly appreciate it, if more information is required please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Array to string Conversion means you tried passing array to a function that expected a string

Comment: wich laravel are you using ?

Comment: @N69S Working with Laravel Framework 8.27.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on the laravel version but try adding a mutator for saving the toppings:

```
/**
     * Set the pizza's toppings.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setToppingsAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['toppings'] = json_encode($value);
    }
```